# Managing frequent flyer miles when split across many different frequent-flyer programs

Tags: loyalty-programs

Mint.com is convenient to have an overview of one's bank/brokerage/retirement accounts. Is there any similar website for  frequent flyer miles?

Comment: One thing I would note is that unless you fly **_a lot_** splitting your miles between a bunch of different programs will make them much more difficult to use, since you can't combine miles between different programs (even within an alliance) for a particular redemption (at least not without going through a points broker and losing a lot of value in the process.)

Comment: AwardWallet is fantastic and very conceptually similar to Mint.com.

Answer (score 5):

I'm familiar with [AwardWallet](https://awardwallet.com/en/), which has both free and paid options, though I've never personally used it. As with Mint, you have to trust them with your data and account information, and there are some [limitations](https://thepointsguy.com/2017/08/keeping-track-of-your-points/), such as United, Delta, and Southwest not allowing them to access accounts (though you can forward your statements in for importing).

[TripIt](https://www.tripit.com) has a [points tracker](https://www.tripit.com/pro/pointtracker) as part of its paid TripIt Pro service.

[points.com](https://www.points.com/) is another option in this space.